# Python Rename relative path with current timestamp

Tags: python, python-2.x

How to check, in Python, if some relative path exist and rename it to current timestamp. 
Example:
path name is /home/folder-20190228/
after starting script i want to check if this path exist and rename it to current timestamp /home/folder-20190301/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether a directory exists with `os.path.isdir` and you will get the current timestamp with the `datetime` library.

```
import datetime
import os

path = "/home/folder-20190228/"
current_timestamp = f"{datetime.datetime.now():%Y%m%d}"

if os.path.isdir(path):
    path = '-'.join([path.split('-')[0], current_timestamp])
```

Comment: no need for {datetime.datetime.now():%Y%m%d}, You can do this with simple localtime()

Comment: That's true but wouldn't you still have to apply some kind of formatting to `localtime` to get it in the form of `yyyymmdd`?